# how to set selected index of select in html using jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I had created a combo box in html using select tag and bind the list to the select. I need to set the select option dynamically to the combobox using jsp. My sample code is given below.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%> 
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import = "Precision.Biometric.PB400.App_Code.*"%>
<%@ page import = "Precision.Biometric.PB400.Presenter.*"%>
<%@ page import = "Precision.Biometric.PB400.Model.*"%>
<%@ page import = "org.joda.time.format.*" %>
<%@ page import = "org.joda.time.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.text.*" %>
<%@ page import = "java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Table/monthtable.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Table/table.css">
<title>Shift Rotation Detail</title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="js/dhtmlgoodies_calendar/dhtmlgoodies_calendar.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery.js">
    </script>

<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" media="screen" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/jquery-1.9.1.js">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.3/ui/jquery-ui.js">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dhtmlgoodies_calendar/dhtmlgoodies_calendar.js">
    </script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MultiDatesPicker/css/mdp.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MultiDatesPicker/css/pepper-ginder-custom.css"/>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="MultiDatesPicker/css/prettify.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="MultiDatesPicker/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js">
    </script>

<body>
<%! String selDay  ="" %>
<%
try
{
List<String> lstWeek = ArrayList<String> ();
lstWeek .add("Sunday");
lstWeek .add("Monday");
lstWeek .add("Tuesday");
lstWeek .add("Wednesday");
lstWeek .add("Thursday");
lstWeek .add("Friday");
lstWeek .add("Saturday");
pageContext.setAttribute("weekList",lstWeek);
if(request.getAttribute("selectedDay")!=null)
             {
                 selDay  = request.getAttribute("selectedDay").toString();
             }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
}
%>
<select name="cmbWeek" id="cmbWeek">
<c:forEach items="${weekList}" var="wkList">
        <option >${wkList}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select><br>
</body>
</html>
```

How to select a particular day using the value of **selDay** ?

Comment: set the value of the select tag to the value you want to be selected.

Comment: That you can achieve by javascript (jquery).

Answer (score 1):

```
<option <c:if test="${selectedDay == wkList}">selected="selected"</c:if>>${wkList}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option <c:if test="${wkList == <%=selDay%>}">selected</c:if>>${wkList}</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Upload Form</title>
<head>
<link href="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/validationEngine.jquery.css?1" rel="tex/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/jquery-1.6.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/jquery.validationEngine.js?1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url()?>/assets/jquery.validationEngine-en.js?1"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#myForm").submit(function(){
        $("#myForm").validationEngine();
        var groupSubject = $.trim($("#groupSubject").val());
            if(event.preventDefault) {
                event.preventDefault();
            } else {
                event.returnValue = false;
            }
        if(groupSubject == ""){
            alert("Please enter Group Subject Name");
            $("#groupSubject").focus();
            return false; 
        }
        var practical = 0;
        var isChecked = $("#practical:checked" ).length;
        if (isChecked == 1)
            practical = 1;
        else
            practical = 0;
        var baseUrl = $("#base_url").val();
        var str = $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: baseUrl+'login/saveGroupSubject',
            type:'post',
            data: str,
            success:function(data){
                    alert(data);
                    getSubjectList();
                    $("#groupSubject").focus();
                } 
            });

    });
    //getSubjectList();
    $(".showdata").change(function(){
        var batchId = $("#batch").val();
        var courseId = $("#course").val();
        if(batchId != "" && courseId !=""){
            getSubjectList();
        }
    });

}); // Ready Function

function getSubjectList(){
    var batchId = $("#batch").val();
    var courseId = $("#course").val();
    var baseUrl = $("#base_url").val();
    if(event.preventDefault) 
    {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
    else
    {
       event.returnValue = false;
    }
    var str = "batchId="+batchId+"&courseId="+courseId
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl+'login/getGroupSubjectList',
        type:'post',
        data: str,
        success:function(data){
                //alert(data);
                $(".groupSubjectList").html(data);
            } 
        });
}

function addOption(a, b, e) {
    var d = new Option(b, e);
    var c = a.length;
    a.options[c] = d
}

function deleteOption(a, c) {
    var b = a.length;
    if (b > 0) {
        a.options[c] = null
    }
}

function moveOptions(f, c) {
    var e = f.length;
    var g = new Array();
    var a = new Array();
    var b = 0;
    var d;
    for (d = e - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
        if (f.options[d].selected) {
            g[b] = f.options[d].text;
            a[b] = f.options[d].value;
            deleteOption(f, d);
            b++
        }
    }
    for (d = b - 1; d >= 0; d--) {
        addOption(c, g[d], a[d])
    }
    return false
}

function hasOptions(a) {
    if (a != null && a.options != null) {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

function swapOptions(f, e, c) {
    var h = f.options;
    var b = h[e].selected;
    var d = h[c].selected;
    var a = new Option(h[e].text, h[e].value, h[e].defaultSelected, h[e].selected);
    var g = new Option(h[c].text, h[c].value, h[c].defaultSelected, h[c].selected);
    h[e] = g;
    h[c] = a;
    h[e].selected = d;
    h[c].selected = b
}

function moveOptionUp(a) {
    if (!hasOptions(a)) {
        return false
    }
    for (i = 0; i < a.options.length; i++) {
        if (a.options[i].selected) {
            if (i != 0 && !a.options[i - 1].selected) {
                swapOptions(a, i, i - 1);
                a.options[i - 1].selected = true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

function moveOptionTop(b) {
    if (!hasOptions(b)) {
        return false
    }
    var a = getSelectedLength(b);
    if (a > 1) {
        alert("You can move a single element to top.");
        return false
    }
    for (i = 0; i < b.options.length; i++) {
        if (i > 0 && i <= b.options.length && b.options[i].selected) {
            var c = i;
            while (c > 0) {
                swapOptions(b, c, --c)
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

function moveOptionDown(a) {
    if (!hasOptions(a)) {
        return false
    }
    for (i = a.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (a.options[i].selected) {
            if (i != (a.options.length - 1) && !a.options[i + 1].selected) {
                swapOptions(a, i, i + 1);
                a.options[i + 1].selected = true
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

function moveOptionBottom(b) {
    if (!hasOptions(b)) {
        return false
    }
    var a = getSelectedLength(b);
    if (a > 1) {
        alert("You can move a single element to bottom.");
        return false
    }
    for (i = 0; i < b.options.length; i++) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < b.options.length && b.options[i].selected) {
            var c = i;
            while (c < (b.options.length - 1)) {
                swapOptions(b, c, ++c)
            }
        }
    }
    return false
}

function getSelectedLength(b) {
    var a = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < b.options.length; i++) {
        if (b.options[i].selected) {
            a++
        }
    }
    return a
};
</script>
<style type="text/css">
li{margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
        <table><form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST">

            <tr><td>Course</td><td>
                <select style="width:250px;" name="children[]" multiple="multiple" size="5" class="showdata validate[required]" id="children">
                <?php
                    for($m =0; $m<count($course); $m++){?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $course[$m]['c_id'];?>"><?php echo $course[$m]['c_name'];?></option>
                    <?php }?>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td><ul>
                    <li title="Move to Top" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="return moveOptionTop(document.getElementById('children'));"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-n">Move Top</span></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li title="Move Up" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="return moveOptionUp(document.getElementById('children'));"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-n">Top</span></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>
                    <li title="Move Down" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="return moveOptionDown(document.getElementById('children'));"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-carat-1-s">Bottom</span></li>
                    <li>&nbsp;</li>       
                    <li title="Move to Bottom" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" onclick="return moveOptionBottom(document.getElementById('children'));"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthickstop-1-s">Move Bottom</span></li>
                  </ul></td>
            </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
        <div class="groupSubjectList"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provde some information and explaination to your code